# while trying to add smb volume to the snapshot set in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, volume-shadow-service

In windows server 2012 R2, While trying to add the smb volume to the snapshot set, i get an error 0x8004230f after calling the AddToSnapshotSet() function. I have searched the error and found some resolutions on http://kb.backupassist.com/articles.php?aid=2971 but it was not helpful for me. Does anyone has a solution for it?